# How to use ccache on a bjam project

Tags: gcc, bjam, ccache

I would like to use ccache for a build done with bjam and gcc as its toolset.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42595807/202526) suggests ccache needs the compilation and linker call in separate steps to work correctly.
However bjam is performing those in a single step.

How can I call/configure bjam to first compile and link afterwards and to work with ccache?

Answer (score 1):

Put in your `~/user-config.jam`

```
using gcc : : ccache g++ ;
```

Now when you request `gcc` toolset (e.g. via `b2 toolset=gcc`) it will use the one initialized above.

> ccache needs the compilation and linker call in separate steps to work correctly. However bjam is performing those in a single step

It's not true, quiet an opposite, b2 **always** perform compilation and likange in separate calls (there is no direct `ASM/C/CPP -> LIB/EXE` generators defined for any toolset).